# A special use of "should"?

Tags: terminology, modal-verbs, bare-conditional

I saw a sentence like this:

> Wilkinson is contesting the release, and threatened to sue should it be released.

I could understand it but do you know what do they call this kind of use of "should" in grammar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This use of "should" appears to be called *expressing the conditional mood*. The New Oxford American Dictionary describes it in the following way:

> (formal) expressing the conditional
> mood
>
> - (in the first person) indicating the consequence of an imagined event:
>   *if I were to obey my first impulse, I should spend my days writing letters*
> - **referring to a possible event or
>   situation**:
>   *if you should change your
>   mind, I'll be at the hotel*
>   *should
>   anyone arrive late, admission is
>   likely to be refused*

(I added emphasis to the part most relevant to your question.)

Often, at least to my ear, this use of "should" carries a connotation of improbability.  Example:

> In the [unlikely] event that you should
> need to complain, please email the management team directly.

Answer (score 7):

I found a nice answer as below:

> These two sentences are very similar in meaning. But 'Should you
>   have...' or 'If you should have...' may be used in preference to 'If
>   you have...' if we want to suggest a slight possibility of something
>   happening or when we are making suggestions or giving advice. Compare:
>
> 'If you have any free time, make sure you visit the old town.' (It's
>   possible, or even likely, that you may have some free time.)
>
> 'If you should have any free time, make sure you visit the old town.'
>   (I don't really expect you will have any free time, but if you do...)
>
> 'Should you fail this exam, you can always re-take it next year.' (I
>   think it's unlikely, but it's possible you may fail it and if you
>   do...)
>
> 'If you fail this exam, you can always re-take it next year.' (I'm
>   just pointing this out to you. I don't have a strong opinion on the
>   matter one way or the other.)

Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv48.shtml

Answer (score 3):

The *if* is simply elided: “If you should have any questions . . . .”

Comment: I don't think so. ["Know you this man?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22know+you+this+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) might be considered an archaic construction, but it seems to me it's the same basic type of word inversion converting a statement into a question/proposition. I don't think there was ever any elided "if" in OP's sentence - that only becomes necessary when you revert the inversion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just because you don’t see them written, doesn’t mean it’s not an “if-then” pairing.  It certainly is.

Comment: If it's simple elision of the word "if", how do you explain the reversal from "should you" to "you should"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s related to the inversion we see not just in leading prepositional phrases, but notably in leading subjunctive used as condition: “Come the day I  pass the bar, I will that day be allowed to practise law” is “When the day comes that I pass the bar...”. It’s archaic, but we use subjunctive mood and inversion for a future hypothetical, the same sort of thing we normally just use a simple *if* and indicative with.  They are equivalent structures in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> **Should you** have any questions, please call

means the same as

> **If you** have any questions, please call

but the former is more formal. Here *[should](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/should_3)* is used as a modal verb with the sense of possibility.