# Are "should" and "if" interchangeable at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, modal-verbs, sentence-starts, bare-conditional

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A special use of “should”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/a-special-use-of-should)

If "should" comes at the beginning of a sentence, and the sentence is not a question, then can it be replaced with "if?" Is there any difference at all?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: Here's an example: "If you declare bankruptcy, your account will be closed." means roughly the same as "Should you declare bankruptcy, your account will be closed."  If you should find any syntactic or semantic differences between the two, please explain by posting your answer.

Comment: Well-spotted, Cerberus.

Answer (score 7):

You can't simply swap the words, as they are grammatically different:

> **If** the sky **is** blue...
>   **Should** the sky **be** blue...

Comment: Marking the subjective in the first example would also be acceptable ("If the sky be blue"), but convey a much more formal, even archaic tone.

Answer (score 3):

- "Should I..."
- "Were I to..."
- "If I..."

Or

- "Should it rain Saturday..."
- "Were it to rain Saturday..."
- "If it rains Saturday..."

These forms all convey the same meaning, but they are very different in style. The only form (of the above) that appears commonly is "If". The others sound formal / poetic / literary.

Answer (score 2):

They're different in the same sense that "Jane kicked the ball" and "The ball was kicked by Jane" are different. They mean the same thing, but the emphasis is different and often one is more appropriate than the other.

Comment: Where does the emphasis lie in the uses of "if" and "should"?