# "Should" cannot replace "if?"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are “should” and “if” interchangeable at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/are-should-and-if-interchangeable-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)
>   [A special use of “should”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/a-special-use-of-should)

For sentences that begin with "If", it seems that "should" can replace "If." For example:

> If you ever...
>
> Should you ever...

However after googling, it seems that "should" should not be used to replace "if." If this is true, then why do people do it?

I also looked up "should" in the dictionary, and I didn't find anything that says it means the same thing as "if."

Answer (score 2):

'Should' is a formal version of 'if'.

From [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/should_3):

> ***formal***, used when referring to a possible event in the future:
>
> *If* anyone should ask for me, I'll be in the manager's office.
>
> *Should* you (= If you) ever need anything, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Then is the "should" in "if you should ever" redundant?

Comment: @language hacker: It depends on your definition of redundant.  You could make the argument that *should* is a completely redundant word since it can also be replaced with "ought to" in other situations.  But so what?

Comment: Good grief, no. _Should_ is not a formal version of _if_, any more than _may_ is the month before June. Both _should_ and _may_ are [modal auxiliary verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) and do not occur alone, nor as conjunctions.