# if or should to ask possibility?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A special use of “should”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/a-special-use-of-should)

I have received an email which was starting wih this:

> Should you have any questions, please call at this number...

So could somebody explain the grammar form of "should" here and why it is preferred over "if".