# The verb “should” as a conjunction

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, subject-verb-inversion, should, bare-conditional

Here is the [phrase from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8#Reception):

> CFO Peter Klein has said that Microsoft has no alternate plan **should** its current mobile strategy fail.

Another example:

> **Should** Microsoft’s tablet and phone efforts continue to inspire little interest among the buying public, don’t expect a radical shift in strategy.

What does the word should mean in this context? The same as *if* or *in case*?

Why is this verb placed before the subject?

I tried to search in dictionaries, but this specific case wasn’t properly explained.

Comment: *Should* is a verb, not a conjunction. English has always supported “bare conditionals” like this (meaning ones without an explicit conjunction connecting the conditional’s *if*-part to its *then*-part). Were it not so, we would have told you. :)

Comment: Ok, it's a duplicate.

Comment: This question gets asked all the time. It is a duplicate of all these:  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26450 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1308 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95943 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20479 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32830 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2631 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66113