# Grammar "should it hold up"

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, should

I read a news about terrorist attack:

> Berger said Kobani, aside from being sole example cited, was a military-style operation, not a terrorist attack, so the formula, should it hold up, might apply only to large-scale sieges.

I know "so" leads the sentence "the formula, should it hold up, might apply only to large-scale sieges." as a conjunction. "Should it hold up" describes the formula.

But "should it hold up" looks like a question sentence. I want to ask the reason why it was written in this structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A special use of "should"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/a-special-use-of-should)

Comment: Please see the definition 3.2 and its second example in the following Oxford Online Dictionary link http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/should

Comment: Oh~I see. The sentence is transferred from "if it should hold up". Thank you!